# What do I do if I want to bind a DataGrid to dynamic data?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

What do I do if I want to bind a DataGrid to dynamic data that doesn't exist as objects with properties?  I want to use the UI power of the DataGrid, but the data schema I have is user generated and so not compiled into a model per se. For example the user can dynamically create new columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wpf DataGrid do support databinding with `DataTable` you can make leverage dynamic data using `DataTable`.

It is not recommended to use `DataTable` but it is okay if you want it to be.

Alternate way I'd suggest is to create a `Model` which holds maximum number of properties which you may require, then let the user choose which they want to see. You can hide or show columns accordingly.

Comment: I will work with DataTable. In order to do what you suggest alternately I would have to create an infinite number of columns. I'm writing software where the user designs the table schema, a model simply doesn't fit this requirement. This leads me to believe that DataGrid is not what I need. Thanks.

Comment: If so `DataTable` will help you.. btw don't forget to mark as answer if that helps :)

Comment: I'll mark it, but the answer I chose was to create my own DataGrid. I found the existing one too limiting and too model-centric for my needs.

Comment: I see, own DataGrid in the sense? Inherits from `DataGrid` or?

Comment: I'm not sure how inheritance friendly DataGrid is. It will be my own control, I think.